# Locus of Triple Cross Product

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

Given 4 coplanar points A,B,C and D how can I find the set of points such that $(MAxMB)x(MBxMC)=0$

I tried simplifying and expanding but I come out with a more complicated expression $OMx(AC+BD)=OAxOB-k(OCxOD)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first expression does not have D.  Is M on the same plane as the others?  How about O?

Comment: And, is that $x$ supposed to be the cross product? $\times$

Comment: For $M \notin AB \cup CD$, $f(M; A,B,C,D) \stackrel{def}{=} (\overrightarrow{MA}\times \overrightarrow{MB} ) \times (\overrightarrow{MC} \times \overrightarrow{MD})$ is $\vec{0}$ when and only when the planes determined by $M,A,B$ and $M,C,D$ coincides. If $A,B,C,D$ are not coplaner, then $f(M; A,B,C,D) = 0$ at and only at $AB \cup CD$. Similarly $f(M;A,B,B,C) = \vec{0}$ when and only when $M$ belongs to the plane determined by $A,B,C$.